# topfunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I want to make a scroll and when I scroll I button appeare and I can click and go back to the top but I have an error that say: `Topfunction is not defined` and I don't know why it's not working. There is my code right there so if you can help me that will be really nice !! Its for a school project !

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
        document.getElementById("monBoutton").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("monBoutton").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#monBoutton {
  /*display: none;*/
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color:#df5791;
  /*color: white;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding: 15px;*/
  /*border-radius: 4px;*/
    background-color: #ffffff00;
}

#monBoutton:hover {
  transform:  scale(2);
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
 /*height: 10px;*/
    width: 7px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px grey; */
    /*border-radius: 20px;*/
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: pink; 
    border-radius:20px;
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrolldown.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="debut.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="monBoutton" title="Go to top">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code here seems to be doing what you described, from what I can see, the error mentions TopFunction with uppercase 'T' while your code has topFunction with lowercase 't', in your local code check the letter case, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Hey! This snippet works perfectly! Is there anything else feature you need?

Comment: Yes! @Lukasz but the error seems to be in the question itself! Not in the code.    `topFunction` has a F in the code.

Comment: omg guys i didn't link the good script !

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works. If you click "run snippet", for instance, you'll notice that the function gets fired.

Getting a "function is not defined" error would certainly mean that wherever the function is, it could not be found. Are you placing it in a separate file, and perhaps missing an import?

Comment: yes you were right my code worked but it was i link in the html !